# Обработка вставки файла из буфера обмена c++ WM_PASTE

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard

Как explorer обрабатывает вставку файлов? При копировании файла в буфер обмена там создается uri ссылка типа file:///C:\myfile.txt. Если я хочу реализовать вставку файлов из буфера обмена в свое приложение я должен получить данные в виде таких uri, потом открыть их в программе и скопировать содержимое?

Возможно ли вставить программно в буфер содержимое самого файла (а не просто uri) при этом чтобы проводник обрабатывал вставку аналогично file:///C:\myfile.txt?

Вообще в идеале мне нужно узнать конечный путь куда был вставлен файл. Допустим есть файлик во временной директории -> я через свою прогу добавляю путь в буфер (file:///C:\Temp\myTmpFile.txt) -> пользователь нажимает в ctrl+v где-то в проводнике -> файлик скопирован. **КАК УЗНАТЬ ПУТЬ** где был вставлен файл?

Comment: Никак не узнать, после заполнения буфера обмена его содержимое живет независимо от приложения.

Comment: Вставить в буфер обмена данные двух типов (mime type) одновременно, например, текст и путь к файлу - можно.  Но, понять как распорядится этими данными программа, которая выполнит вставку - нельзя.

Comment: Ок. Решение тогда - использовать перехват CreateFile в проводнике через inject DLL